# error : object has no attribute 'get_via_uri'" in post object in tastypie

Tags: python, django, tastypie

i am new to django getting error while posting data:

```
{    "name": "My family",
     "title": "Wassup",
     "gallery":"/api/v1/gallery/1/"
}
```

to end point : `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/images/`
"error_message": "'Gallery' object has no attribute 'get_via_uri'"

models.py

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)


class Image(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

resources.py

```
class GalleryResource(ModelResource):
    images = fields.ToManyField(
        'gallery_app.resources.ImageResource',
        'images',
        full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Gallery.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'gallery'


class ImageResource(ModelResource):
    gallery = fields.ForeignKey(Gallery, 'gallery')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Image.objects.all()
        authorization = Authorization()
        resource_name = 'images'
```

pip freeze

```
Django==1.6.5
Pillow==2.5.1
South==1.0
argparse==1.2.1
django-tastypie==0.11.1
python-dateutil==2.2
python-mimeparse==0.1.4
six==1.7.3
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

kindly suggest some good project build on tastypie based api to reference . thanks .

Comment: regarding reference project : i found internal test files to be great https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/tree/master/tests/related_resource

Comment: just stop using tastypie and switch for Django Rest Framework :)

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the model Gallery in your ImageResource, you should be referring to the GalleryResource.

```
class ImageResource(ModelResource):
  gallery = fields.ForeignKey(GalleryResource, 'gallery')

  class Meta:
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
    authorization = Authorization()
    resource_name = 'images'
```

Refer: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships